# How can I avoid MatchCollection processing faults?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am using a matchcollection such as:

```
matches = new Regex(ABS_URL_REGEX, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled).Matches(TargetText);
```

In this case the Regex expression is matching for URL values:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'" + "\"" + ".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

The Regex itself runs very quickly but the application hangs when checking for results:

```
if (matches != null && matches.Count > 0)
```

If I take out the count part, this call will go through quickly but then get stuck on the next line:

```
foreach (Match thisMatch in matches)
```

The most common culprit appears to be when there are 0 matches.  So how do I check for results without experiencing these hang issues?

Comment: FYI:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b49yw9s8.aspx

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Thank you going to 4.5 did the trick!